# How to fetch enrolled courses from Learndash in Elementor Loop Grid?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, learndash

I'm trying to fetch the enrolled courses for the user in an elementor loop grid but it is throwing error:

"`PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 6340739072 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /www/be10x_939/public/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/notes/user/capabilities.php on line 37".`

Here's the code:

```
// Elementor Query for Learndash
function get_learndash_enrolled_courses_query() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        // error_log($user_id);
        if (function_exists('learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses')) {
        // Function exists, proceed with your code
            $enrolled_courses = learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses($user_id, array(), false);
            error_log($enrolled_courses);
            return new WP_Query([
                'post_type' => 'sfwd-courses',
                'post__in' => $enrolled_courses,
            ]);
        } else {
            error_log('learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses function not found');
        }
    }
    return null;
}
add_action('elementor/query/aryn_learndash_enrolled_courses', function($query) {
    $custom_query = get_learndash_enrolled_courses_query();
    
    // Check if courses are found and modify the query accordingly
    if (!empty($enrolled_courses)) {
        error_log($custom_query);
        if ($custom_query) {
            $query->set('post__in', $custom_query->posts);
            $query->set('post_type', 'sfwd-courses');
        }
    }

});
```

I tried using multiple codes, but this was the most optimized but, it did not work. I'm expecting the function to return the courses for each user using the ELementor widget.